# Drop external file

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, drag-and-drop

Im using Jquery ui. I want to drop a external file in a dropzone and get just the path of the file. I think i have to overwrite the default function `window.drop`. But im not sure how to do it or what to write instead ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't get the local file path in JavaScript, for security reasons.

Comment: it must be possible somehow, because its allready implemented for uploading a file with a button, its somehow done by a fake input field ...

Comment: @user1011185: Have a look at the question I linked to, above.